# C++ registry handling without .NET

Tags: c++, visual-studio, registry

For a script that will check/set a Windows registry value. No GUI.
Am writing in Visual Studio, but do not want .NET - just C++.

However, I haven't figured out where and what methods exist natively in C++ [NOT Visual C++]
that interface with the registry.
I also haven't worked out how to compile C++ code in Visual Studio 2010 without .NET.

Can someone please direct me to the documentation (or even better, tutorials) of the standard C++ registry related methods.
And furnish me with instructions or point out a tutorial that will allow a complete and total noob to compile in VS a non .NET program.

Please do NOT argue about my aversion to .NET, that has been the subject of other threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a native C++ console application in VS 2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46e82t5z.aspx

To check/set registry values using Win32 APIs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[Windows Registry Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Generally the flow goes something like:

1. Open the registry key with `RegOpenKeyEx`. The last parameter is a pointer to a registry key handle for the opened key (if the open is successful).
2. Using the returned registry key, you can set its value using `RegSetValueEx`, you can add new subkeys using `RegCreateKeyEx`, and delete keys using `RegDeleteKey`.
3. Close any opened or created keys using `RegCloseKey`.

There is a tutorial to be found [here](http://www.hellboundhackers.org/articles/918-windows-registry-using-c++-and-win32-api.html).

Unfortunately I don't use VS, so I'm not the person to help you with compiling "vanilla" C++ in that. That said though, I imagine it shouldn't be all that difficult - there's probably an option somewhere for a "Plain C++" project.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) a list of all of the native functions for interacting with the registry.  The most useful ones are probably `RegOpenKeyEx`, `RegQueryValueEx`, `RegSetValueEx`, and `RegCloseKey`.

A number of good articles describing usage of the registry can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724182%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use mfc. This shows how
http://www.endurasoft.com/techtalk/regdemo1.htm

or atl
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xka57xy4(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Why, exactly, is this a better idea than using the Windows API functions directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Stlsoft](http://stlsoft.org)'s [registry components](http://www.stlsoft.org/doc-1.9/group__group____library____windows__registry.html) for an STL-like interface.